# How should I fail a test when an if condition becomes false

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I want a test to fail when the `if` condition below becomes `false`.

```
last_url = self.browser.current_url

if 'https://***/news/' in last_url:
    print("test passed")
else:
    #Test should fail if it reaches here
    print("test failed")
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
assert 'https://***/news/' in last_url
```

You can try it in Python console:

```
>>> last_url = 'https://***/news/page.jsp'
>>> assert 'https://***/news/' in last_url
>>> last_url = 'https://***/no-news/page.jsp'
>>> assert 'https://***/news/' in last_url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Comment: Nice, concise answer.  +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`self.fail(msg="…")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.fail).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Asset in this case, below is the dummy code try this. I have used Java based code here you can, you can change as the language which you are using.

```
int isURLMatching =0;

if 'https://***/news/' in last_url:
    print("test passed")
isURLMatching++;
Assert.assertTrue("message", isURLMatching>0);

else:
    #Test should fail if it reaches here
    print("test failed")
isURLMatching=0;
Assert.assertFalse("message", isURLMatching==0);
```

Comment: This mixes Python with Java.

Comment: @dzieciou and i think that's why i have mentioned the same in the comment above the code. Which clearly says what is required to be changed.